# Orderby meta_value_num and page attribute order

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to order some karate instructors by their belt order, and if two instructors have the same belt degree, use page attribute "order" to finegrain control order amongst the same degree instructors.

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'mudo-instructor',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'perm'              => 'readable',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'          => 'instructor-degree',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
    );
```

the meta_key is a radio button ACF field

The desired result should look something like this:

- Inspector 1 - 4 degree blackbelt (page attribute: order 0 (default))
- Inspector 2 - 3 degree blackbelt (page attribute: order 0 (default))
- Inspector 3 - 3 degree blackbelt (page attribute: order 0 (default))
- Inspector 4 - 2 degree blackbelt (page attribute: order 1)
- Inspector 5 - 2 degree blackbelt (page attribute: order 2)
- Inspector 6 - 2 degree blackbelt (page attribute: order 3)
- Inspector 7 - 1 degree blackbelt (page attribute: order 0 (default))

I tried orderby array, like:

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
    'orderby' => array(
    'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    ),
    'meta_key'          => 'instructor-degree',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
    );
```

But the result was that my instructors witch had page attribute order 0 got output first then at the bottom all the instructors with page attribute 1 etc, kinda at a loss here.

Comment: Are you just looking to reverse the order or what exactly? expectations are not clear.